# setfitsystemwindows not working windowtranslucentstatus coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, statusbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am working on a small Android project.  I am having some problems while displaying the toolbar below the status bar. I am using the following config:

- Support library version 23.2.0
- windowTranslucentStatus = true

```
<CollapsingToolbarLayout fitSystemWindows="true" ...>
<FrameLayout fitSystemWindows="true" ...>
<ViewPager>
....consists a fragment with framelayout and image
</ViewPager>

<Toolbar fitSystemWindows="true" ...>

</FrameLayout>

<CollapsingToolbarLayout fitSystemWindows="true"...>
.....
</AppBarLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>`
```

[image: Image is displayed correctly but not the toolbar]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_musicplayer_appBarlayout_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_musicexplorer_album_collapsingtoolbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="#eab22b"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/fragment_musicplayer_viewpager_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/fragment_musicplayer_toolbar_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change some of `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to **`android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`**, it may work.

I faced similar problem with yours with Support library version **23.2.0**, and then searched StackOverflow; found your question.

My case was opposite to yours because mine didn't need top-margin spacing but it had. Although I set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`, but nothing changed.

But I found that you set **`windowTranslucentStatus = true`** and so did I. It was a key clue.

I dared to change `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` to `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. It worked.

It may be that the behavior of `android:fitsSystemWindows` has been changed. Possibly it has been inverted when `windowTranslucentStatus = true`.

--But there remains a problem. When the toolbar is collapsed, the bottom bound of the toolbar is still aligned wrongly. I've forced to abandon to use `windowTranslucentStatus = true`...

**EDIT**: [23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions) was released and the bottom bound problem was fixed. But the above suggestion that the behavior of **`android:fitsSystemWindows`** has been inverted is still true.

Comment: Hi, I am going to try it. Generally I think, I am doing everything right, windowTranslucentStatus=true for displaying the Viewpager-Fragment behind the statusbar and fitSystemWindows=true to display the toolbar below the statusbar

Comment: @hata , after so many tries to make translucent status bar work with Cordinator layout on KK, it seems we should let the status bar dark like ICS and JB and only make it transparent or translucent for 21+ :(